# How to include a PHP web file into the content region. from a module

Tags: 7, blocks

I am new to Drupal and PHP. I am trying to create a module that when activated creates a page, then creates a block, configures block to only show on the created page, and then display an included PHP file. The PHP file that is included is for accessing an off site database.

I have managed to code the module to create the page, and create the block. But the following is my issue.

In the hook_block_view, for content I have input a function name, below I defined the function to include testpage.inc. that page loads but the content does not load in the block's specified region. If I just input text for the content, it loads in the region no problem.

> ```
> <?php
>
> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> /** using hook_menu to create a page for the module - hook_menu**/
> /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> function sps_webconnect_menu() {
>   $items['products']=array(
>       'title' => 'Products',
>       'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
>       'page callback' => 'sps_webconnect_products',
>       'access callback' => TRUE,
>       );
>   return $items;
> }
>
> /** This function defines the page callback from above**/
> function sps_webconnect_products() {
>   return "&nbsp";
> }
>
> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> /** Creates and Defines Block - hook_block_info**/
> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> function sps_webconnect_block_info() {
>   $blocks['sps_webconnect_block'] = array(
>       'info' => t('Products Page - SPS Web Connect'),
>       'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
>       'status' => TRUE,
>       'region' => 'content',
>       'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
>       'pages' => 'products',
>   );
>   return $blocks;
> }
>
>
> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> /* This function defines the content of the block - hook_block_view */
> /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> function sps_webconnect_block_view($delta = '') {
>   $block = array();
>
>   switch ($delta) {
>     case 'sps_webconnect_block':
>       $block['subject'] = t('SPS Product Page');
>       $block['content'] = sps_webconnect_file();
>       break;
>   }
>   return $block;
> }
>
>
> function sps_webconnect_file(){
>   $output = '';
>   module_load_include('inc', 'sps_webconnect', 'testpage');
>   return $output;
> }
> ```

Comment: You are including a file but never assigning anything to $output

Comment: What is in testpage.inc? You are just loading inc file, without doing anything with `$output`, so why would you expect any changes in `$output`? (Damn, @J.Reynolds was faster to write that)

Comment: Like I said i'm new to PHP and Drupal. Should I move the module_load_include to be the output value?

Comment: I want testpage.inc ( this will be a php webfile that accesses an off site database.) to be the output. when I do this, the file is included but it is outside of the block. inside the block is the path to testpage.inc